# Would that be correct ? I finished eating at 7:30 AM. = I have eaten at 7:30 AM

Tags: tenses, time, perfect-aspect

Would that be correct ?
I finished eating at 7:30 AM. = I have eaten at 7:30 AM.

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking if the two sentences are interchangeable? Or, if one is more appropriate than the other? What happened to the "finished" in your second sentence? I.e., *I have finished eating at 7.30 am.* What do you know about the simple past and the present perfect usage?

Answer (score 3):

Without further context, "I have eaten at 7:30 AM" indicates that at some time in the past, at least once, you have eaten at that time.

A statement closer in meaning to your first, and similar in form to your second, would be "I had eaten by 7:30 AM", indicating that you had completed the process of stuffing food into your gullet by that time.

Answer (score 1):

The *present perfect* covers time from an unspecified past moment up to the present.  Thus, "have eaten" clashes with a specific time, which more naturally takes the **simple past**:

> Q: *Have* you *eaten*?  [i.e., During some past time interval]
>   A: I **ate** at 7:30.

The present perfect would work with a habitual activity, something you did at various mornings in the past, possibly up to this morning:

> Q: Do you **eat** breakfast early?  [Note the **enduring present** for activity continuing from the past]
>   A: I *have eaten* at 7:30.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly.

"I finished eating at 7:30 AM" indicates that at 7:30 AM, you were eating and completed your meal at that time, while "I have eaten at 7:30 AM" only indicates that you were eating at that time.

Comment: "I have eaten at 7:30" is wrong.

Comment: @Jacinto What exactly is wrong about it?

Comment: Only thing I see wrong here is a lengthy hard to read sentence.  "I have eaten at 7:30 AM" is perfectly correct grammar that indeed indicates that at 7:30 AM you were eating.

Comment: The only sense in which I can find "I have eaten at 7:30" making sense is that mentioned in other answers "There has been at least one occasion in the past when I ate at 7:30". I cannot make it mean that you were eating at that time today/yesterday.